# How do I transform the info I got in JSON into a DOUBLE so I can use the info correctly?

Tags: json, swift

The error that occurred:

[image: The error that occurred]

The structure I put the data in:

[image: The structure I put the data in]

The function call that got the JSON information in the first place]:

[image: The function call that got the JSON information in the first place]

The information sent into another structure:

[image: The information sent into another structure]

I am writing a connected car app using the smart car API. I have a node.js backend running on Heroku and a Swift 4 frontend that I run on my iPad.

When I compile the app to run on my iPad it runs fine.
It goes through the authentication process but what happens is I get this error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x100f16054)

on the first of these right here

var carLatitude:Double = carInfo.latitude as! Double

var carLongitude:Double = carInfo.longitude as! Double

As you see from the code below I create a structure named code data. Then in `Alamofire.request("\(Constants.appServer)/location",`
I get a JSON document and save it to an instance of the structure `carData` called `teslaCar`.

Then I save the `teslaCar` to the `carInfo` structure to transfer it to another view.

I then try to simply get the `carInfo.latitude` and `carInfo.longitude` into a variable and turn it into a double. I am having the hardest trouble in the world transferring the latitude and longitude into a double. Once it is transferred correctly, I will display it on mapkit.

Can someone tell me how to make this work?

```
import Alamofire
import UIKit
import SmartcarAuth
import SwiftyJSON

struct carData {
    var make: String = ""
    var model: String = ""
    var year: String = ""
    var latitude: String = ""
    var longitude: String = ""
    var odometer: String = ""
}

    
            Alamofire.request("\(Constants.appServer)/location", method: .get).responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let value):
                    let json = JSON(value)
                    print("JSON: \(json)")
                    
                    let latitude = json["data"]["latitude"].stringValue
                    let longitude = json["data"]["longitude"].stringValue
                    let locationDeclaration = "Latitude: \(latitude) and Longitude: \(longitude)"
                    self.vehicleLocationText = locationDeclaration
                    print(json["data"]["latitude"])
                    print(json["data"]["longitude"])
                    
                    self.teslaCar.latitude = latitude
                    self.teslaCar.longitude = longitude
                  /*   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "displayVehicleInfo", sender: self)
 */
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
                
               
            }

        override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if var destinationVC = segue.destination as? InfoViewController {
            destinationVC.carInfo = teslaCar
        
        }



       var carLatitude:Double = carInfo.latitude as! Double
        var carLongitude:Double = carInfo.longitude as! Double
```

When

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the error message carefully.

> Cast from `String` to unrelated type `Double` always fails.

If you cannot **cast** a type to another you have to use an initializer method to **convert** the type.

And please read also the yellow warnings and consider the suggestions to declare unmutated *var*iables as constants

```
let carLatitude = Double(carInfo.latitude) ?? 0.0
let carLongitude = Double(carInfo.longitude) ?? 0.0
```

The `?? 0.0` part assignes `0.0` if the string value cannot be converted to `Double`

For more information about type conversion please read [The Basics in Swift Language Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html)

Comment: This completely worked. Thank you very much. This is the answer. You linked me to the Swift Basics. Thanks for that. But where in the swift basics link you sent me does the  "?? 0.0" get talked about? I looked for it and couldn't find it. Thanks!

Comment: The *nil-coalescing operator* is described in the next chapter [Basic Operators](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html#ID72)

Answer (score 0):

[This is the fixed version of the code with the changes that @vadian made. It now works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrfAj.png)
[This is the map function that I wrote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZ0D0.png)

[This is a screen shot of the operational program from the iPad thanks to @vadian's help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OccSR.png)

The answer is to write this code

```
       let carLatitude = Double(carInfo.latitude) ?? 0.0
    let carLongitude = Double(carInfo.longitude) ?? 0.0

        let initialLocation = CLLocation(latitude: carLatitude ?? 0.0, longitude: carLongitude ?? 0.0)
```

It was not only necessary to use a method and send the variable I was trying to convert as a parameter but also add a `?? 0.0`

and then when I was passing the variable I created to the MapKit function called "CLLocation" it was necessary to add a `?? 0.0`

For some reason that is how you make things that are considered a type of `Any` be an `Any`

That is the answer as far as I can describe. There are better ways to explain it that's just the best I could say.